# Unity 3d model fragmented on mobile

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, shader, blender, 3d-model

I have a strange issue that keeps coming up in Unity 2018.2.15f1 (personal). The best way to describe it is that my 3D models are fragmenting (exploding? shattering?) when I build to iOS. So, I'll start with a visual explanation. This is what the model looks like on an iPad

[image: fragmented model]

and this is what it should look like ([you can also see it on the App Store w/o fragmenting](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-speed-of-thinking/id1263001692)):

[image: OK view]

These models came from OSM terrain data, worked on in Blender, and then imported to Unity. They worked fine on mobile builds up until one of two things happened while trying to increase performance 1) I experimented with mobile shaders and 2) I followed some of the tips in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogaWex7HzaA). Since discovering the issue I "undid" all the changes (using Git this was easy) and it seemed to fix it, until many versions later the problem has suddenly showed up again, but **only on this one model** (not the other two "cities"). I assumed the issue was the switch to mobile shaders, but since I'm not using them any long I now have no idea what is causing the issue.

Here's what I've done to try to fix it:

1. Reimported the model
2. Broken the model into distinct components (buildings and terrain)
3. Double checked I have default Quality settings (under Project Settings)
4. Double checked I use only the Standard Unity shader throughout the game
5. **I have found if I turn off one or the other of two models in the scene (the buildings and terrain) the issue goes away.**
6. **I have found if I position the building model so they don't intersect (see #5) it works *sometimes* but not every time. It must be at least 30 units above the terrain on the Y axis before the fragments go away.**
7. I tried writing over the iOS build folder (instead of append) but that had no effect.
8. I tried switching to PC standalone, resetting the GI Cache in Preferences, and switching back to iOS but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found <del>the</del> a solution, but I don't know why. I separated the meshes into separate objects AND gave each a different material, with matching settings except for one option.

[image]

On the new one,  I changed the Rendering Mode from Opaque to Transparent. Now there is no more fragmenting, but I'm not sure why. Leaving this question open until someone knows the answer.

[image]